# *ERROR* timed out waiting for panel to power on

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, boot, intel

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on Asus VX6 (1.8GHz Atom - 2 cores, optimus nVidia ION) with Kernel 3.9.0.

When I start my system I get this error:

```
[   15.728106] [drm:intel_enable_lvds] *ERROR* timed out waiting for panel to power on
```

I get it even with older kernels.

What does it mean and how can I make it stop?

I tried to google something, but all I found were threads where the actual problem was something else.

..................

lspci -vv: https://files.myopera.com/BS-Harou/files/ub-lspcivv.txt

Comment: How do you know the problem was something else?

Comment: Well, usually they asked about some other problem that I don't have. Everything works fine, I just don't like mysterious error messages :)

Comment: Please paste the output of 'lspci -vv' executed as root.

Comment: Done, I put a link to the question.

Comment: Apparently, other users with your hardware have this issue, and it's completely harmless.

Comment: Thx. Do you think I should fill a bug report somewhere or it is just supposed to print this?

Comment: If the kernel is Ubuntu, use their bugtracking system. If it's a vanilla kernel, bugzilla.kernel.org .